# Browser console.log() not showing in terminal

Tags: meteor

I have just started a new meteor application following a tutorial. Meteor is running the app on my local host and when I enter 'console.log("Hello world");' in the browser console:

```
console.log("Hello world");
Hello world
undefined
```

When I check my terminal console there is nothing showing up there:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Started your app.   

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

I'm using Mac Os X, Google Chrome and I've ensured the following are added on meteor (if its even relevant):

```
meteor add autopublish
meteor add insecure
```

Moreover, the html and js files meteor has created in my app folder have no code in them.

Thanks.

S

Comment: Can you describe what do you expect to happen? Your output looks correct to me? You executed console.log only on the client side: browser, the log will not magically appear on the server console unless some code is executed on server.

Comment: see docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter `console.log("Hello world");` in the browser console, you're running the code in your browser only.

Try put a `main.js` at the root of your project folder, and write down `console.log("Hello world");` in it, then you'll get log messages in both terminal console and browser console.

This is because main.js runs in both environment.

Code in `/client` run in browser only, and code in `/server` run in server only.
Code that is not in `/client` or `/server` runs in both browser and server.

For more details, see http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp